# Sharing recyclerview item ID with another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Currently I have a recyclerview adapter that gets data from the database and displays it in the dashboard fragment. Once the item is clicked, I want to pass the item id to the details fragment to get the correct items information on the detailed view. How can I pass this ID to the detailed fragment?

**Dashboard Fragment**

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: DashboardViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Get a reference to the binding object and inflate the fragment views.
        val binding:  DashboardFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        val dataSource = NumberDatabase.getInstance(application).numberDatabaseDao

        val viewModelFactory = DashboardViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)


        // Get a reference to the ViewModel associated with this fragment.
        val dashboardViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(
                        this, viewModelFactory).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)

        // To use the View Model with data binding, you have to explicitly
        // give the binding object a reference to it.
        binding.dashboardViewModel = dashboardViewModel

        val adapter = CounterAdapter(CounterListener { nightId ->
            dashboardViewModel.onCountClicked(nightId)
        })


        binding.counterList.adapter = adapter

        dashboardViewModel.counts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })
}
```

**Adapter**

```
class CounterAdapter (val clickListener: CounterListener): ListAdapter<Number, CounterAdapter.ViewHolder>(NightDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, clickListener)
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }


    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ListItemCounterBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        fun bind(item: Number, clickListener: CounterListener) {
            binding.night = item
            binding.clickListener = clickListener

            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ListItemCounterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class CounterListener(val clickListener: (nightId: Long) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(night: Number) = clickListener(night.nightId)
    }
```

Comment: Use `setArguments` of Fragment to send `nightId` .

Comment: Use `dashboardViewModel` in your fragment and observe the nightId

Comment: Can you share more code of your fragment and adapter

Comment: I assume you wanted to pass the nightId which you got through Counter listener from the dashboard fragment to the other fragment .If so ,if other fragment is in the same activity as dashboard fragment you can use interface to communicate with the fragments .it will be better if you share more code.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your recyclerview

   ```
    class RecipeRecyclerAdapter(
     mFragmentCommunication: FragmentCommunication
    ) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    private var mFragmentCommunication: FragmentCommunication? = null


    init {
   this.mFragmentCommunication =mFragmentCommunication

         }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
     RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

           view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
               .inflate(
                   com.broadcast.recipeslistapp.R.layout.layout_recipe_list_item,
                   parent,
                   false
               )
             return RecipeViewHolder(view)

       }


     }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      if (mRecipes.isNullOrEmpty()) {
       return 0
      } else {
       return mRecipes!!.size
   }
   }

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {


   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
       mFragmentCommunication!!.PassNightId(nightId = 1) //value of nightId
      }

     }


   interface FragmentCommunication {
   fun PassNightId(nightId: Int)
   }
   ```

Fragment A from where you want to send data :

```
class RecipeListActivity : BaseActivity(),
RecipeRecyclerAdapter.FragmentCommunication {

private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager


}

private fun initRecyclerView() {
    mAdapter = RecipeRecyclerAdapter( this)
    val itemDecorator = VerticalSpacingItemDecorator(30);
    recipe_list.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);
    recipe_list.adapter = mAdapter
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recipe_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
}


override fun PassNightId(nightId: Int) {
    val testFragment = TestFragment()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("nightId", "$nightId")
    testFragment.arguments = bundle
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerId,testFragment).commit()

   }
  }
```

Fragment B where you want to getData :

```
 class TestFragment  : Fragment()
{


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val nightId =arguments?.getString("nightId")

}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment,container,false)
}
 }
```

This is how you can send data from on fragment to another fragment.